# Removing eg. (UTC, +0100, +0200, +seconds ) from the timezone RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I'm trying to learn some rails and it's moving forward, but something that bothers me is as the title says, the ending of the timestamp. As im swedish i modified it to display my correct timezone.

EG: `2014-08-20 13:24:51 +0200`

But what i want to see is `2014-08-20 13:24`

To display the time for each post i use

```
<% @blog_posts.reverse_each do |blog_post| %>
    <h3><%= blog_post.title %></h3>
    <p> <%= blog_post.created_at.to_s %> </p>
    <p>
      <%= simple_format(blog_post.body) %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Anyone with a simple idea to solve the issue?

Comment: Search for strftime and/or i18n.localize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails you can use the to_time function on a string to convert it into a Date object:

```
> '2014-8-20 14:27:46'.to_time.strftime('%B %e at %l:%M %p')
=> "August 20 at 2:27 PM"
```

[`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) Format Directives:

- `%B` Full month name
- `%e` Day of the month
- `%l` Hour of the day
- `%M` Minute of the hour
- `%p` Meridian indicator (AM/PM)

Comment: I really like this idea, however it display as you show `"August and PM"` do you happen to know how to make it display with a different language? like swedish it's `Augusti 20 2:27 EM`

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear  .For that you might need to ask a different question , please do select the answer if you found it helpful .

Comment: Using the function `.to_time.strftime('%B %e at %l:%M %p')` displays in english `August 20 at 2:27 PM` however for swedish users it "should" look like `Augusti 20 2:27 EM`, do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes , for that you will have to look into internationalization , it involves setting locales and once done it will convert all the dates to swedish. More on it here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html .

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<%= blog_post.created_at.to_s %>
```

Or use [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime):

```
<%= blog_post.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %>
```

Comment: Tried this and restarted the server, but it didn't seem to work. It still display the second value and the ending (+0200)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_formatted_s` method:

```
<%= blog_post.created_at.to_formatted_s(:db) %>
```

It will show `seconds` also. If you want only date, hours and minute, try:

```
<%= blog_post.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at method strftime from ruby class Time

```
<%= blog_post.cteated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M") %>
```

This link could be helpfull too 
[Strfti.me](http://www.strfti.me/)

**EDIT:**

For localize your time you must use localize or l => <%= l post.created_at %>
first download yours locale yml file from [Rails locale files](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/68727a3c549cb29708ad71129e28d0ac32c88a95/rails/locale)
copy the raw file to the conifg/locales.
In this file you could set yours default strftime:

> ```
> formats: 
>   default: "%B %e at %l:%M %p"
> ```

Then in your application.rb

> config.i18n.default_locale = :pl // for me is pl :)

and finally in your view

> l blog_post.created_at

Hope that help you :)

Comment: This works, i might have to update the question, but it would be great if you were able to help me out as GhostBuster stated to display "August 20" but with the swedish input "Augusti 20"

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<%= @user.created_at.to_date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)%> => July 5th, 2014

<%=@user.created_at.strftime("%b %d,%Y") %> =>  Jul 05,2014
```

...whichever u prefer